# How to convert a series of images as a slideshow and single images as inline images?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I need `xslt` to treat a series of images using `<media>` tags as a slideshow and single images as inline images. I have logic to find `<media>` surrounded by `<p>` tags but extending it to handle all non `<media>` tags is tedious. How could I write some kind of `not(p)` logic that works in xslt 1.0?

Here is the xslt (I've removed the full call-template code since it is not important):

```
<xsl:template name="textImage">
        <xsl:param name="paragraphs"/>
        <xsl:variable name="paragraphCount" select="count($paragraphs)"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$paragraphs">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="mediaReference">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <!--single media block-->
                        <xsl:when test="ancestor::table or position() = $paragraphCount or (position() = 1 and (generate-id(following-sibling::*[1]) != generate-id(following-sibling::media[1]))) or (generate-id(preceding-sibling::p[1]/following-sibling::media[1]) = generate-id(current()) and generate-id(following-sibling::p[1]/preceding-sibling::media[1]) = generate-id(current()))">
                            <xsl:call-template name="imageNode"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <!--two more pam:media blocks for a carousel-->
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="generate-id(preceding-sibling::p[1]/following-sibling::media[1]) = generate-id(current())">
                                    <xsl:call-template name="firstImageNode"/>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="generate-id(following-sibling::p[1]/preceding-sibling::media[1]) = generate-id(current())">
                                    <xsl:call-template name="lastImageNode"/>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                    <xsl:call-template name="imageNode"/>
                                </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:call-template name="textNode"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
```

Here is some sample xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<message>
    <article xml:lang="en-US">
        <body>
            <h2>What a Chicken!</h2>
            <media>
                <mediaReference refid="BA_chicken1.jpg"/>
            </media>
            <ol>
                <li>
                    <p>Place chicken breast side down.</p>
                </li>
            </ol>
            <media>
                <mediaReference refid="BA_chicken2.jpg"/>
            </media>
            <media>
                <mediaReference refid="BA_chicken3.jpg"/>
            </media>
            <p>More about chickens</p>
            <media>
                <mediaReference refid="BA_chicken4.jpg"/>
            </media>
            <p>The End</p>
        </body>
    </article>
</message>
```

Correct output looks something like:

```
<h2>What a Chicken!</h2>
<img src="BA_chicken1.jpg">
<ol><li>
    <p>Place chicken breast side down.</p>
</li></ol>
<div class="slideshow">
    <img src="BA_chicken2.jpg">
    <img src="BA_chicken3.jpg">
</div>
<p>More about chickens</p>
<img src="BA_chicken4.jpg">
<p>The End</p>
```

Comment: What is the logic of images? All but first go into the *slideshow* div? Also, the namespace `pam:` must be declared prior to using. You may have left that out in posting sample.

Comment: The pam namespace is left out of the sample, but is not important to the matching. I need to make each group of two more images into a slideshow and leave the single images as inline images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you would benefit from an approach making better use of match templates. If you start with the identity template, you would have separate templates to match your various situations, such as whether it is an individual or in a group, and for consecutive ones you have a recursive template to process the consecutive elements one at a time.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:pam="pam">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <!-- Ignore media elements with direct preceding siblings as these are processed elsewhere -->
    <xsl:template match="pam:media[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::pam:media]]" priority="2" />

    <!-- First of a group -->
    <xsl:template match="pam:media[following-sibling::*[1][self::pam:media]]">
      <div class="image">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="self::*" mode="image" />
      </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Individual -->
    <xsl:template match="pam:media">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="self::*" mode="image" />
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Template that actually creates the image -->
    <xsl:template match="pam:media" mode="image">
        <img src="{pam:mediaReference/@pam:refid}" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1][self::pam:media]" mode="image" />
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Identity Template -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I note that your XSLT seems to distinguish between the first and last element in a group, although your output XML does not show this. One way to adapt this answer to handle this is to amend the "image" mode template to keep a running count to allow it to check if it is the first or last node in a group.

For example, this updated template adds a different class on to the first and last elements:

```
<xsl:template match="pam:media" mode="image">
    <xsl:param name="position" select="1" />
    <xsl:variable name="nextElement" select="following-sibling::*[1][self::pam:media]" />
    <img src="{pam:mediaReference/@pam:refid}">
        <xsl:attribute name="class">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$position = 1 and $nextElement">first image</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$position > 1 and not($nextElement)">last image</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>image</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </img>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$nextElement" mode="image">
        <xsl:with-param name="position" select="$position + 1" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I do need to keep track of the start and end of the group so that I write the correct opening and closing to the slideshow. I eliminated some the node writing from the xslt because it did not change the logic and made for a lot of boilerplate to read.

Comment: I created a named-template version of your updated template that works great. Thanks so much for pointing out that I can use variables to store information about previous and next elements.